# i don't want any space between two divs, how can i do this?

Tags: html, css

Getting unwanted spaces between two divs , how can I do this? I mean there are two option like div 1 and div 2 and i don't want any spaces between them. I have tried with margin bottom, but it's not working. Here's my Code-

HTML

```
<a href="fee.html" style="text-decoration:none;">
<div class="div" style="margin-bottom:0px;"> 
<h2>OFFERS</h2> </div></a>
 <a href="dept.html" style="text-decoration:none">
<div class="div"> <h2>CALL RATES</h2> </div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.div {  
text-align: left;
width:81%;
line-height: 298%;    
 opacity: .8;
margin-left:0%;
margin-bottom:0px;
 border-radius:7px;
 background-color: hsl(0, 69%, 22%) !important;
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#b42121", endColorstr="#5e1111");
  background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b42121), to(#5e1111));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b42121, #5e1111);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b42121, #5e1111);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #b42121), color-stop(100%, #5e1111));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b42121, #5e1111);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b42121, #5e1111);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#b42121, #5e1111);
  border-color: #5e1111 #5e1111 hsl(0, 69%, 17%);
  color: #fff !important;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Comment: And where is the HTML?

Comment: <a href="fee.html" style="text-decoration:none;"><div class="div" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
<h2>OFFERS</h2>
</div></a>

<a href="dept.html" style="text-decoration:none"><div class="div">
<h2>CALL RATES</h2>
</div></a>

Comment: sorry this is my first time here, so it's getting tough for me to understand the system here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove margin from `h2`

```css
h2 {
    margin:0px    /*set margin 0px*/
}
.div {
    text-align: left;
    width:81%;
    line-height: 298%;
    opacity: .8;
    margin-left:0%;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    border-radius:7px;
    background-color: hsl(0, 69%, 22%) !important;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#b42121", endColorstr="#5e1111");
    background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b42121), to(#5e1111));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b42121, #5e1111);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b42121, #5e1111);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #b42121), color-stop(100%, #5e1111));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b42121, #5e1111);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b42121, #5e1111);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#b42121, #5e1111);
    border-color: #5e1111 #5e1111 hsl(0, 69%, 17%);
    color: #fff !important;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

```html
<a href="fee.html" style="text-decoration:none;">
<div class="div" style="margin-bottom:0px;"> 
<h2>OFFERS</h2> </div></a>
 <a href="dept.html" style="text-decoration:none">
<div class="div"> <h2>CALL RATES</h2> </div>
</a>
```

Comment: thank you soo much! =D really appreciate your help! ^_^

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the `<div>`, it's your `<h2>`. By default, `h` tags have margin.

Set the margin on the `<h2>` to `0`

```
h2 {
margin:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fd8grojc/

Comment: If you open your console in your browser and hover over the element it should highlight on the screen. If there is orange around it, that is a margin, and if it is green it is padding I believe. (at least for chrome, not sure about other browsers)